# How to use collapse method in react google charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization, orgchart

I am using react google charts in my project. In the org charts I need to call collapse event but I am getting error you can't use collapse.

code:

```
<Chart
  width={"100%"}
  height={350}
  chartType="OrgChart"
  loader={<RenderSpinner />}
  data={data}
  options={{
    title: "Member designation charts",
    allowHtml: true,
    allowCollapse: true,
    selectedNodeClass: "selected-class",
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
  }}
    chartEvents={[
      {
        eventName: "collapse",
        callback({ chartWrapper }) {
          chartWrapper.getChart().collapse(2,true)
        }
      }
    ]}
  rootProps={{ "data-testid": "1" }}
  className="chart-wrapper"
/>
```

Guide me how to use this. Thanks In advance

Comment: according to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts#listen-to-chart-events) --> _The callback has the component as an argument._ -- on which you would call collapse --> `chartWrapper.getChart().collapse`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated chartEvents. I am getting 
Property 'collapse' does not exist error